# Vue.js - Unable to trigger DOM update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

so I have a complex nested structure that is like so in my Vue app's data:

```js
{
  x: {
    y: [{
      z: {
        a: 1
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Although I used `v-model` in a v-for with the child property, setting `.z.a = 2` doesn't seem to trigger this in the UI. I figured ok, must be that I'm mutating a property without alerting Vue, no biggie I just need to use `Vue.set`.

So I tried the following:

```js
Vue.set(app.x.y[0].z, "a", 2)
Vue.set(app.x.y[0], "z", {a:2})
Vue.set(app.x.y, 0, app.x.y[0]) // app.x.y[0] is definitely {z:{a: 2}}
Vue.set(app.x, "y", app.y)
app.x.y = app.x.y.map(_ => _)
```

While these all usually do the trick for me, in this case it doesn't seem to work. If it changes things, I'm using `v-model` instead of a traditional prop, so it would be synced back to the app. I wonder if perhaps this disassociates the `app.x` and the actual data property for x.

I'm looking for a way to trigger a DOM update or properly set the value in Vue. I've also tried an `app.$forceUpdate()` to no avail :/

EDIT:
While I wasn't able to make Vue observe the change by itself, I found that I had a function that was populating `z` after it had been initialized to {}. I assume Vue set watchers on `z` the moment it was initialized, and so did not observe any further changed (i.e. adding `a` in the next line). Changing this to populate every possible property on initialization, combined with any of the `.set`'s above and a `$forceUpdate`, I was able to trigger a DOM update. It's a temporary workaround though and I'd really like to be able to have Vue automatically observe this update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [vue computed property or watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). This will automatically detect the changed in your data and update the v-model data you have.

In this example a change in the returned value of message will automatically be applied to the input.

```
<input v-model="message">

computed: {
    message(){
        return {x:{y:[1,2,3]}}
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fire as well, it seems Vue is not detecting the change at all unless I explicitly initialize the properties initially and use `.set` and `.forceUpdate`. I would also like to operate on the property directly without defining a duplicate to sync.